# поставить на крон php скрипт

Tags: php, modx, cron, phpexcel

как можно поставить этот скрипт на cron, чтобы выгрузился весь товар в excel?

```
  $sql = "SELECT `modx_site_content`.id,".$select." FROM `modx_site_content` 
                left join `modx_ms2_products` on `modx_ms2_products`.id = `modx_site_content`.id
                where `modx_site_content`.`template` = 31 and `context_key`='web' AND ".$where."";
            $statement = $modx->query($sql);
            $parent = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $i = 3;
            $cost = 0;
            $j= 0;
            foreach ($parent as $result) {
                    $j++;
                    if ($vendor == 1){
                        $sqlVendor = "SELECT `modx_ms2_vendors`.name FROM `modx_ms2_products` 
                            left join `modx_ms2_vendors` on `modx_ms2_vendors`.id = `modx_ms2_products`.`vendor`
                            where `modx_ms2_products`.id = ".$result['id']." LIMIT 1";
                         //echo $sqlVendor;
                        $statementv = $modx->query($sqlVendor);
                        $parentv = $statementv->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        foreach ($parentv as $res) {
                            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                            ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $res['name']);
                        }
                    }
                    if ($composition == 1){
                        $sqlComposition = "SELECT * FROM `modx_ms2_product_options` 
                            where product_id = ".$result['id']." LIMIT 1";
                        //echo $sqlComposition;
                        $statementc = $modx->query($sqlComposition);
                        $parentc = $statementc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        foreach ($parentc as $res) {
                            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                            ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $res['value']);
                        }
                    }
                    if ($size == 1){
                        $sizeStr = '';
                        foreach(json_decode($result['size']) as $item) {
                          $sizeStr.=$item.$_POST['delimeter'];
                        }
                        $sizeStr = substr($sizeStr,0,-1);
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->setCellValue('J'.$i, $sizeStr);
                    }
                    if ($color == 1){
                        $colorStr = '';
                        $sqlColor = "SELECT * FROM `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` WHERE `tmplvarid`=2 and `contentid`=".$result['id']." limit 1";
                        $statementc = $modx->query($sqlColor);
                        $parentc = $statementc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        foreach ($parentc as $res) {
                            $nojson = json_decode($res['value'], true);
                            foreach($nojson as $row){
                                $colorStr.=$row['colorname'].';'.$row['color'].$_POST['delimeter'];
                            }
                            $colorStr = substr($colorStr,0,-1);

                            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                            ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $colorStr);
                        }
                    }
                    if ($_POST['images']){
                        $gallery = '';
                        $sqlPath = "SELECT * FROM `modx_ms2_product_files` WHERE `product_id`=".$result['id']." limit 1";
                        $statementc = $modx->query($sqlPath);
                        $parentc = $statementc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $files[] += $result['id'];
                        foreach ($parentc as $res) {
                            $filelist = array();
                            if($handle = opendir('images/products/'.$res['path'].'thumb/')){
                                while($entry = readdir($handle)){
                                    $gallery.='https://kristroom.ru/assets/images/products/'.$res['path'].$entry.$_POST['delimeter'];
                                }

                                closedir($handle);
                            }
                            $gallery = substr($gallery,0,-1);

                            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                            ->setCellValue('I'.$i, $gallery);
                            $gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/products/'.$res['path'].$res['file']);
                            $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
                            $objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
                            $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
                            $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
                            $objDrawing->setWidth(50);
                            $objDrawing->setHeight(50);
                            $objDrawing->setCoordinates('L'.$i);
                            $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
                        }
                    }
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $result['pagetitle'])
                    ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $result['article'])
                    ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $result['alias'])
                    ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $result['content'])
                    ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $result['image'])
                    ->setCellValue('K'.$i, $result['price']);
                    $i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Отредактируйте файл /etc/cron.d
Где укажите периодичность, и выполняемую команду

```
* * * * *  php /path/to/script.php
```

все звездочки будут запускать скрипт каждую минуту
[Подробности](https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/)

Comment: да, а саму выгрузку нужно изменить? просто хочу сделать, чтобы после полного экспорта по крону, файл отправлялся на почту пользователю

Comment: Cron просто запустит ваш скрипт, так-же как если бы вы запускали его через браузер. Если у вас в сценарии есть инструкция на отправление email и он без ошибок дойдет до нее, то он попытается ее выполнить. Если вы протестировали ваш скрипт в обычном режиме и все работает, то проблем скорее всего не будет.

Comment: https://kristroom.ru/vyigruzka-tovarov сейчас когда выгружаю товар выскакивает 502 ошибка + я отправляю через ajax POST переменные

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502 Причины могут быть и не связаны с вашим кодом, вам нужно продебажить и убедится что каждая часть кода работает корректно. плюс POST в cron команду вы передавать не сможете

Comment: они посоветовали сменить хостинг где 990рв месяц

Comment: Кто они? Mozilla?

Comment: хостер на новом тарифе нет ограничения на max_execution_time

Comment: вот что выдает лог
Jun 18 14:05:01 vh182 mcpu_log: [2019-06-18 11:04:16] cw89159 apache2 (10122) used 45% CPU time in 6 seconds. 3 hits, 1 left
Jun 18 14:05:01 vh182 mcpu_log: [2019-06-18 11:04:21] cw89159 apache2 (10122) used 59% CPU time in 5 seconds. 4 hits, 0 left
Jun 18 14:05:01 vh182 mcpu_log: [2019-06-18 11:04:26] cw89159 apache2 (10122) used 59% CPU time in 5 seconds. 5 hits, sent SIGTERM

Comment: Также проблема однозначно существует на стороне  каталога, мне не удалось сделать оттуда выгрузку, для начала убедитесь что выгрузка работает отдельно

Comment: если поставить например только пальто то работает, если больше товаров выгружать то шибка

Comment: я попытался выгрузить пальто, и попал на вывод ошибки с открытым sql, это говорит об очень больших технических причинах на этом сайте.
Протестируйте свой скрипт на собственном файле xls
Так или иначе, к крону это отношения не имеет

Comment: это не ошибка, я сделал вывод sql для тестирования экспорта